# WebSocket-ы на андроид

Tags: java, android, websocket

Пишу мессенджер на Android. Серверная часть написана на весеннем ботинке (`spring boot`). Сейчас взаимодействие с сервером происходит посредством переодических http запросов. Но это нагружает систему и жрет интернет. Хочу настроить связь через сокеты. Как настроить спринг на работу с сокетами я нашел, и примерно понял механизм. Но как на андроиде подключиться к серверу? Все примеры либо на `javscript`, либо описывают только механизм открытия сокета, но как подписаться на конкретный адрес на сервере(например:
http ://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx/user/{user_id}/new_messages), я не разобрался. Понял, что вроде популярная библиотека `nv_websocket_client`. Но дальше этого не пошло дело. Перелопатил уже все, что только можно.

Comment: Кажется, у вас есть какая-то очень конкретная проблема. Наверное в указании конкретного адреса для подключения. По идее, если у вас есть на сервере адрес, куда можно подключиться, то просто на клиенте его указываете и всё работает. Если не работает - то или адрес не так указываете либо на сервере таки не работает.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб То есть никаких дополнительных библиотек для работы со STOMP не нужно? Можно все сделать силами nv_websocket_java? Я просто вообще ничего не понимаю в этой теме

Comment: Надо смотреть доку к либе. Может там и есть поддержка. Если нет - попробуйте вот эту: https://github.com/NaikSoftware/StompProtocolAndroid